# different time in API response at first call and then call again?

Tags: laravel, postman

I created an API in Laravel.
When I first call the API in Postman it shows 504ms, then I call it again and it shows 235ms in Postman. If I call it once again it returns about 220ms to 280ms max?

If I stop  making calls to the api for few minutes (about 10-15 min) when I call it again it takes around 500ms for the first time and then it shows  near 200.

Is it cached data or persistence call or Zend opCache?

Can anybody help me find out why or what is this?

Comment: This is possibly related to cache. Do you cache anything in your code? What php version are you using? Do you have opcache?

Comment: It's just the cache. Try going to settings and see if there are any cache settings

Answer (score 0):

Laravel supports popular caching backends like Memcached and Redis out of the box. But if you are not using their facades inside your application you shouldnt have any of this issues. Your problem is not the laravel but your server/environment configuration.